# useEffect dependency with Context API. My code works fine with empty array but still gives the warning

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-context, use-context

So. I get clients from context as initialState and the code below is from my listing component (listClients.js or smth) . I update the context with the data fetched from firebase. Everything works fine actully with using empty array as dependency. I get my final array listed on my list component.. But eslint is still saying me that I should add "clientsRef" and "updateClients" into dependency but this causes an infinite loop. So what should I do with that? Close my eyes to this warning?

```
const { clients, removeClient, updateClients } = useContext(ClientsContext);
const collection = 'clients';
const clientsRef = firestore.collection('clients').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc');


useEffect(() => {

    const unsubscribeFromSnapshot = clientsRef.onSnapshot(async snapshot => {
        const clientsMap = convertSnapshotToMap(snapshot);
        updateClients(clientsMap);     

    });

    return () => {
        unsubscribeFromSnapshot();
    }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the clientsRef within the useEffect and for updateCloients function you can make use of `useCallback` in the ContextProvider. Once you do that you can add them as a dependency to useEffect

```
const { clients, removeClient, updateClients } = useContext(ClientsContext);



useEffect(() => {
    const collection = 'clients';
     const clientsRef = firestore.collection('clients').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc');
    const unsubscribeFromSnapshot = clientsRef.onSnapshot(async snapshot => {
        const clientsMap = convertSnapshotToMap(snapshot);
        updateClients(clientsMap);     

    });

    return () => {
        unsubscribeFromSnapshot();
    }
}, []);
```

---

In ClientContext Provider

```
const updateClients = useCallback(() => {
   // logic here
}, []);
```

However if you are sure that you just want the logic within useEffect to run once and not anytime later, you can disable the warning with

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Ex:

```
useEffect(() => {

    const unsubscribeFromSnapshot = clientsRef.onSnapshot(async snapshot => {
        const clientsMap = convertSnapshotToMap(snapshot);
        updateClients(clientsMap);     

    });

    return () => {
        unsubscribeFromSnapshot();
    }
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

For more details please check this post:

[How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook/55854902#55854902)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. useCallback rocks. Only [updateClients] was enough after doing as you said.

Comment: Happy to have helped :-)